# Changing labels after swithiching between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, timer

I have two-views app for iPhone. On first one I call code that does this every second with NSTimer:

1. update variables
2. make sound
3. update label
4. update image position

When I start app - everything works perfect. When I go to other view and then go back to first screen - 1 and 2 works fine, but 3 and 4 resets and does not work at all.

What could be the problem?

Looks like it loses "hooks" to elements...

```
-(void)countup {
DeccelFloat += 0.4;
SpeedFloat += 5/(DeccelFloat);
SpeedInt = lroundf(SpeedFloat);
speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SpeedInt];
imageview.center = CGPointMake(imageview.center.x, imageview.center.y+3);
if (imageview.center.y < 280)  {
    imageview.alpha = 1;
    if (SpeedFloat > MaxSpeedValue) {
        [self playalarm];
    }else{
        [self playbeep]; 
    }
}
if ((imageview.center.y >= 280) && (imageview.center.y < 283))   {
    if (SpeedFloat > MaxSpeedValue) {
        [self playshot];
    }else{
        [self playbeepbeep];
    }
}
if ((imageview.center.y >= 280) && (imageview.center.y < 350))  {
    imageview.alpha = 0.5-(0.5/70)*(imageview.center.y - 280);
}
if (imageview.center.y >= 350)  {
    imageview.alpha = 0;
    imageview.center = CGPointMake(imageview.center.x, 180);
}
}
```

And here is my timer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MaxSpeedValue = 60;


    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSNumber *maxspeedsetttings = nil;
    NSNumber *blinkingsetttings = nil;
    NSNumber *startedsetttings = nil;
    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        maxspeedsetttings = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"maxspeedsetttings"];
        blinkingsetttings = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"blinkingsetttings"];
        startedsetttings = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"startedsetttings"];
    }

    MaxSpeedDef = [maxspeedsetttings intValue];
    if (MaxSpeedDef == 1) {
        maxspeed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MaxSpeedValue];

    }else{
        maxspeed.alpha = 0;
        maxspeedlabel.alpha = 0;
    }




        imageview.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                                 nil];
        imageview.animationDuration = 1;
        imageview.animationRepeatCount = 0;


        BlinkingDef = [blinkingsetttings intValue];  
        if (BlinkingDef == 1) {
            [imageview startAnimating];
        }else{
            [imageview stopAnimating];
        }
        [self.view addSubview:imageview];

    StartedDef = [startedsetttings intValue];
    if (StartedDef == 0) {
        SpeedFloat = 0;
        DeccelFloat = 0;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        StartedDef = 1;
        if (standardUserDefaults) {
            [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:StartedDef] forKey:@"startedsetttings"];
            [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Having a look at your codes will be good for us!!!

Comment: Added. StartedDef just makes it start once&